# Import fixtures into running firebase emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I'm using emulator to run my unit tests, with fixtures to run more easily my integrations and units tests :

```
firebase emulators:start  --import=../fixtures/unit-tests
```

But when I'm writing something throught my test to firebase emulator, I cannot clear the data without removing all the fixtures.

For eg. there is this command :

```
firebase.clearFirestoreData({
  projectId: "my-project"
});
```

But this will remove all my data (fixture included). I want to clear my database without deleteting fixtures.

**TLDR :**

Is there a way to re-import fixtures into a running emulator or clear data without deleting fixtures ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the AdminApp abilities and store your fixtures as JSON files and create your collections before each test.